What makes a question too elementary?
Here is a link to a question that I posted:
My Question
Here is a link to another question:
Another Question
Given that my question was too elementary, I do not understand why the second question is not too elementary. Please tell me why it is not.

The community votes to close based on the guidelines set out in the help.
